# SQL Hiding Duplicate Addresses in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a mailing list in SQL Server 2008 where we show all addresses for employees, however, many employees share the same address and we don't want have duplicate addresses on the list. My current query is not working.

How can I hide the rows that contain duplicate addresses?

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  empid, 'empfirstname + emplastname', 
  empaddress, empaddress2, empzipcode, empcity,empstate,empcountry
from emp
group by empaddress
```

This is what I currently see:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. A few lines of data can help us a lot understand what you need.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: What mean `ISNT Working` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window analytic function `row_number()` that works on most of the Database Management Systems ( since we don't know yours, yet )

```
select *
from
(
select
  name, address, country, ID, -- due to the data on the picture
  row_number() over (partition by address order by id) as rn 
from emp
) q
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
select
  e.empid, e.empfirstname + e.emplastname, 
  e.empaddress, e.empaddress2, e.empzipcode,
  e.empcity, e.empstate, e.empcountry
from emp e
where not exists (
  select 1 from emp
  where id < e.id and empaddress = e.empaddress and empzipcode = e.empzipcode
)
```

I guess `empaddress` and `empzipcode` are enough to define a distinct address.